upgrading to latest version of intellij has broken the ability to command click on angularjs functions
Just upgraded to the latest version of IntelliJ IDEA 2024.2.2
I have an html page with this code in it
<button ng-click="addNumberToCampaign()" class="btn btn-success" >Submit</button>

Previously I could command click into the function addNumberToCampaign, now I can not. the editor/IDE does not recognize it as a function.
I have tried , clear and invalidate and repair IDE
Not even sure where to look or search on how to resolve this.
Thanks

There were no AngularJS-related changes in 2024.2.2, and I haven't been able to reproduce them so far. Could you submit an issue at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB and provide more details on your case?

@Oksana. This is a humongous project and I am sure if i create a new small project everything will be fine. Any other suggestions
